# How to add extruder to RAMBo Mini

Tags: extruder

I have given up on getting the RUMBA board to work. I tried to add a P.I.N.D.A. (or PINDA) probe, but that didn’t work. I tried to add a BLTouch sensor, but that didn’t work either. Now the RUMBA board is not communicating with my PC.

So I have moved on to using a Mini-Rambo but the one drawback is that it only has one extruder capability. I would like to know if there is any way to add an extruder to the Mini-Rambo. Whether it be a separate board or soldering or something. I am open to anything.

Comment: This question needs more information to answer. E.g. some pictures of the board and the brand. Please add information by [edit].

Comment: It sounds like you should post *another* question (or two), relating to why you can't get your RUMBA board to work :-) One for the PINDA and one for the BLTouch. When/if you do, please include in your questions, what exact steps you have tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the clue is in the name, [*Mini*RAMBo](https://reprap.org/wiki/MiniRambo). The *Mini* part is related to its diminutive size and reduced functionality.

Extending the board would require patching in a secondary board to the MiniRAMBo board via pins<sup>1</sup> that may or may not exist, and would probably be more trouble than it is worth.

Looking at the [board layout](https://reprap.org/wiki/File:MiniRambo1.3a-connections.png) certainly shows that there are not any readily available connections for such an expansion.

[image]

If you want two extruders then the [RAMBo](https://reprap.org/wiki/Rambo) would be a better bet, as it has 5 stepper motor driver outputs. It would certainly be easier, and quicker (as well as cheaper) than a MiniRAMBo plus a secondary daughter board).

That said, as the MiniRAMBo has two Z-axis controllers, it *may* be possible to repurpose one of them, *if* they are wired independently of each other and separately controllable. Although these lines suggest otherwise:

> It has 4 stepper drivers and 4 mosfet switched outputs.

and

> #### Differences from Rambo
>
> MiniRambo has:
>
> - 4 stepper drivers vs. 5

and

> Motor Drivers
>
> 4 A4982 1/16th microstep motor drivers(2 connectors on Z for Prusa
> Mendel and other dual Z printer designs)

So, it would appear that the two Z axis drivers are wired together.

---

<sup>1</sup> By *pins*, I mean external board pins/connectors - rather than the pins of the µController itself

Comment: The two Z connectors *are*, in fact, controlled by a single driver. I also thought it is the mini-Rambo, therefore the request to the OP to expand the answer. That board is very limited, exposing more pins would mean soldering to the microprocessor, which is pretty impossible for most people.

Comment: I've added a clarification. Thanks for pointing out the confusing line :-)